# Modifying link so IE doesn't raise XSS Issue?

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, xss

Is there a way to modify a link so IE will properly show the page?

For example, I am working with Ruby, and have a list generated, such as a link like:

```
https://www.google.com/search?img=bks&q="cats" OR "dogs" or "birds"
```

However, when I click that link, which opens in a new tab/window, IE raises the following issue:

```
Internet Explorer has modified this page to help prevent cross-site scripting.
```

And the page doesn't load at all.  The link is also loaded into the address bar as such:

```
https://www.google.com/search?img=bks&q=%22cats%22%20OR%20%22dogs%22%20OR%20%22birds%22
```

Obviously, the above example is not what I am working with, but what causes IE to do this?  Interestingly, if I do something like:

```
https://www.google.com/search?img=bks&q=%22cats%22
```

OR

```
https://www.google.com/search?img=bks&q=%22cats%22%20OR%20%22dogs%22
```

It works fine, oddly enough.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you not URL encoding for your link? Are you literally linking to `"cats" OR "dogs" or "birds"` in the query string, or are you linking to `%22cats%22%20OR%20%22dogs%22%20OR%20%22birds%22`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get around anti-`XSS` measures by using hexadecimal or decimal string representations, as IE doesn't see that as an injection. So if you have `DOG` write it as `&#68;&#79;&#71;`. You can use [this](http://www.hashemian.com/tools/html-url-encode-decode.php) site as a decimal encoding tool and read more about IE's `XSS` injection workarounds [here](https://www.whitehatsec.com/blog/internet-explorer-xss-filter/).

Comment: Thanks!  I will be using some library to work this all out.